# Android Studio Error: E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-studio-3.0, rippledrawable

I was working on a project and this error suddenly appeared:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

I reverted the app to a previous version which was working, and the error persisted. i created a new project, with an empty activity and ran it on my device, the error persisted. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing to fix. This is merely mentioning that your code (e.g., a library) has a reference to a class (`android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable`) that is not available on your device. Most likely, your device is running Android 4.4 or older, as this class was introduced in Android 5.0.

This particular message comes up all the time, as our code (e.g., `appcompat-v7`) often refers to classes that we would like to use on newer devices but can avoid on older devices.

So, just ignore it.

Comment: Same problem on 4.4 with dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader not found